# Update my ASP.NET MVC4 project templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

There are plenty of references around to ajax login form capability in the asp.net mvc4 Internet Application project template, and also references to related artifacts such as `AjaxLogin.js` and method `ContextDependentView()`.

When I created a new project/solution from this template I don't see the ajax login and I don't find these artifacts.

Is this because I don't have the latest version of the templates?  If so how do I refresh them?

I'm using VS2012 premium update 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Developer release of Visual Studio 11 (later called Visual Studio 2012) included a single page application (SPA) template that used this AjaxLogin.js and ContextDependentView() methods.  This was removed from the final release for whatever reason, and was unsupported.  I'm sure the references you're seeing are for this developer preview version.

However, there is another SPA template out now, included in (IIRC) Update 2.  If you create a new MVC 4 project, then you should see Single Page Application listed.  This one just has a method called JsonLogin.